# open multiple canary chrome browser windows via batch file

Tags: javascript, html, windows, google-chrome, batch-file

I am trying to open multiple windows via batch file in Chrome Canary. I can do it via regular Chrome, but when I try inserting info for Canary and launch it opens up a data file so I think the issue is maybe a directory issue.

Regular Chrome (works)

```
start "" "c:\program files (x86)\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe" --app="data:text/html,<html><body><script>window.moveTo(300,50);window.resizeTo(250,200);window.location='URL-HERE';</script></body></html>
```

Chrome Canary (that I cant get working)

```
start "" "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe" —app="data:text/html,<html><body><script>window.moveTo(50,250);window.resizeTo(250,200);window.location='URL_HERE';</script></body></html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the executables accept the same parameters?  Also, it appears that you have double quotation marks in the path of the "Canary" example, is that intentional?  It looks like your parameters for the javascript are different as well, is the URL different as well (Since you don't include it here)?

Comment: double quotation- I just now saw it, Thank you. That was part of the issue

Answer (score 0):

try the following :

```
start "" "C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe" --app="data:text/html,<html><body><script>window.moveTo(50,250);window.resizeTo(250,200);window.location='http://www.google.com';</script></body></html>"
```

It worked on my side.

Comment: Progress!  Thankyou! It actually opened up the browser.

 I entered a url, but it didn't open or resize